# c# What happens if I use code a .NET 3.5 function on a machine that has .Net 2 installed

Tags: c#

Just out of interest, if I built some code using the Enumerable.Distinct function which appeared in .Net 3.5 and then ran it on a machine with .Net 2.0 on it, what would happen?

Comment: Note this is not something I want to do! I almost did it accidentally a few days ago and wandered what would have happened :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program will crash as soon as the assembly that defines `Enumerable.Distinct` (System.Core) is needed. However, you can make it work if you target .NET 2.0 and use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) instead of System.Core.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to compile a 3.5 Framework project and run it on the 2.0 Framework as long as you don't have any 3.5 Framework references.  In your case, you are using `Enumerable.Distinct` which is in the 3.5 Framework references, so your application will fail.

Answer (score 2):

.Net 2.0 won't understand the command because the library isn't there.

Comment: So would the code crash, throw an exception? What would the user see?

Comment: @Richard, it will crash because it can't find the System.Core assembly

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 is essentially .NET 2.0 + some extra assemblies.

If those extra assemblies aren't installed, ie. .NET 3.5 isn't installed, then your program will fail to load those assemblies when needed.

If you have somehow managed to steer clear of using those assemblies, then presumably your program will function just fine, but I'd say that would be the exception to the rule. For your specific example, at the point where your program uses .NET 3.5 code for the first time, you would get an exception.

In short, make sure .NET 3.5 (SP1) is installed on the target machines.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your code will complain about .net 3.5 being not installed at the startup.

Answer (score 1):

Simple,It will crash at aribitary points at where you used  the .net 3.5 specific functionality.

But basic question ... why do you want to do that ?

If you have migrated a project from .net freamework version 2.0 to 3.5 and not using any feature of .net 3.5 does not represent a valid framework migration

Comment: I don't want to do that. We have a number of clients on .NET platforms between 2 and 4 and I thought the other day I'd compiled something to 3.5 and released. I hadn't but wandered what would happen if I did accidentally.